# What's the latest, free version of Visual Studio that can create C# SQL Server 2008 r2 CLR Assemblies?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, .net-assembly

We're running SQL 2008 r2 Standard (we have Enterprise, but I'm waiting for IT to install it), I have some complex logic I need to write and T-SQL is just not cutting it.  I currently have BIDS 2008 and Visual Studio 2015 Communnity installed.  I know BIDS won't work, and I can't seem to figure out what type of project/template I need for VS 2015 (if it exists for it).

**My question is:** What is the latest (or best/most features), free version of Visual Studio that can create C# SQL Server 2008 r2 CLR Assemblies?  Can I just download and run VS 2012 Express or something?

Normally money isn't an issue, but I don't have time to get it approved.  Once I get rolling, which paid version would you recommend?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 uses **.NET 2.0** as its CLR - so any version of Visual Studio that can target .NET 2.0 should be fine - and this even includes the most recent VS 2015 (Express and/or Community)

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't even consider that. I now have my solution/project setup, connected to my DB, and I see the CLR and 2008 options in the items and properties fields!  Submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 uses **.NET 2.0** as its SQL-embedded CLR.

So any version of Visual Studio that can (still) target .NET 2.0 should be fine.

This includes the most recent VS 2015 (both the **FREE** Express and / or Community editions).